# Вырезать данные с помощью split или slice (JS)

Tags: javascript

Добрый день, у меня есть строка в виде `100 ($50)`. Помогите вывести с этой строки число `50`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
console.log("100 ($50)".split("$")[1].split(")")[0])
```

Даже не представляю, зачем вам это... Есть же регулярки(хоть я их и не изучал даже)

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)

Answer (score 3):

```js
var s = "100 ($50)";
var res = s.match(/\(\$(\d+)\)/)[1];
console.log(res);
```